# Why JavaFX stucks when running a process?

Tags: mysql, javafx, keyevent, actionevent

I am building an application using JavaFX. Application does some CRUD operations with the MySQL Database. So currently, I have 2 functions.

1. User Registration.
2. Email Validation (Check if email already exists in the database).

User registration is called in a JFoenix Button event. When it clicked it is calling separate 3 functions in another class as follows,

```
public static int insertUser(User user) {
    int status = 0;

    try {
        Connection con = DbConnection.getConnection();  
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (name, password, email, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");  
        ps.setString(1, user.getName());  
        ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());  
        ps.setString(3, user.getEmail());  
        ps.setString(4, user.getCountry());

        status = ps.executeUpdate();  

        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;  
}

public static int updateTime(String email, String timestamp) {
    int status = 0;

    try {
        Connection con = DbConnection.getConnection();  
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET timestamp = ? WHERE email = ?");
        ps.setString(1, timestamp);
        ps.setString(2, email);

        status = ps.executeUpdate();  

        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;  
}
```

The problem is when I click the Button I see it is getting stuck while running that process. So I put that code inside the following,

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    try {

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
});
```

Now it is somewhat okay but I see it is getting a little stuck after clicking (Ripple effect is not working well and also the mouse hover effect is not working as usual).

And Email Validation is done when the user types an email in the text field and the key released event is triggered and it is checking for the database result. The code for checking email is as follows,

```
public static boolean emailAvailability(String email) {
    boolean status = false;

    try {
        Connection con = DbConnection.getConnection();  
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        ps.setString(1, email);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        status = rs.next();

        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;  
}
```

In the key event also it is getting stuck more. Can't type a character for some milliseconds.

I don't see any issue with my code because I have done this many times with Java Swing and all are perfectly working fine in Swing. And if a button is getting stuck with the running process I just put those codes inside the following and it works perfect,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

   }
}).start();
```

I am not going to or trying to compare Java Swing and JavaFX But I need to know why JavaFX is behaving like this? What should I do to avoid this and run the program smoothly with the CSS effects if it is a huge process or not? Really appreciate it if anybody can help me. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here is my `signUp` code. Executes when button clicks,

```
private void signUp(ActionEvent event) {
    if (name.getText.equals("") && name.getText().isEmpty()) {
        if (!name.getStyleClass().contains("error-class")) {
            name.getStyleClass().add("error-class");
            nameImageValidation.setImage(new Image("danger.png"));
            nameImageValidation.setVisible(true);
        }
    } else {
        name.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("error-class"));
        nameImageValidation.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (password.getText.equals("") && password.getText().isEmpty()) {
        if (!password.getStyleClass().contains("error-class")) {
            password.getStyleClass().add("error-class");
            passwordImageValidation.setImage(new Image("danger.png"));
            passwordImageValidation.setVisible(false);
        }
    } else {
        password.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("error-class"));
        passwordImageValidation.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (email.getText.equals("") && email.getText().isEmpty()) {
        if (!email.getStyleClass().contains("error-class")) {
            email.getStyleClass().add("error-class");
            emailImageValidation.setImage(new Image("danger.png"));
            emailImageValidation.setVisible(false);
        }
    } else {
        email.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("error-class"));
        emailImageValidation.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (country.getText.equals("") && country.getText().isEmpty()) {
        if (!country.getStyleClass().contains("error-class")) {
            country.getStyleClass().add("error-class");
            countryImageValidation.setImage(new Image("danger.png"));
            countryImageValidation.setVisible(false);
        }
    } else {
        country.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("error-class"));
        countryImageValidation.setVisible(false);
    }

    if(emailValidation() && passwordValidation() && fieldsValidation()) {
        User user = new User(name.getText(), email.getText(), password.getText(), country.getText());

        int insertStatus = UserController.insertUser(user);

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (insertStatus > 0) {
            int updateStatus = UserController.updateTime(email.getText(), timestamp.toString());

                if(updateStatus > 0) {
                    // Go to Login Page
                } else {
                    showAlert(); // Error Message
                }
        } else {
            showAlert(); // Error Message
        }
    } else {
        showAlert(); // Error Message
    }
}
```

Here the `validateEmail` code. Executes when user typing the email. Triggered when Key Released and when performing this after type a character have to wait some time and then appear next character and go...

```
private void validateEmail(KeyEvent event) {
    boolean status = UserController.emailAvailability(email.getText());

    if (!status) {
        email.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("success-class"));
        emailImageValidation.setImage(new Image("safe.png"));
        emailImageValidation.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        email.getStyleClass().removeIf(style -> style.equals("error-class"));
        emailImageValidation.setImage(new Image("danger.png"));
        emailImageValidation.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no 'process' here, only some database updates, which need to happen on their own thread, as they are blocking operations.

Comment: @user207421 Process means it is a signup process. Insert and Update data.

Comment: unrelated: don't use static scope

Answer (score 2):

When you trigger a function from the GUI, execution happens in the main thread. Now, these calls are blocking, which means that until they return, the main thread can't update the GUI.

There are generally two ways to solve this:

1. Async functions, that yield (allows other code to run) until the resource they are waiting for become available

   2. Threads, which means running part of the program in parrallel, which most likely will require you to think about locks etc.

I suggest you look into these two things, as they are quite central to making good apps that are connected to other services and IO

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am running signup process inside the `Platform.runLater`. Why is that also getting stucked? And why Swing is working perfectly with these situations?

Comment: I can't say anything about swing as I've hardly ever touched that. As for the platform.runLater I'd refer you to the documentation. What it does is it queues your code to run in the main thread at an unspecified time, so javafx will run it when it decides to. This is good for updating the UI from async code, but if calling blocking code, the code will still be running in your GUI thread and thus block it's updates.

Comment: Oh, and the docs on Platform class are here btw. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html

Comment: When I am going to create a `Thread` JavaFX throws this error. `Threads in JavaFX: Not on FX application thread` Why is that? I can't create new thread(new Runnable) thread in JavaFX.

Comment: @TechGuy All long-running tasks, including blocking calls, **must** be done on a background thread. However, all updates to the UI **must** be done on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. The `Platform.runLater` method schedules an action to be executed on the **FX thread** and is typically used to post updates to the UI from a background thread. Look into using a `javafx.concurrent.Task` as that class provides an API for communicating with the FX thread—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: @TechGuy And Swing has the exact same requirements as JavaFX in this regard. Both are single-threaded and not thread-safe. With Swing, however, the UI thread is the _Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)_. If your code is working in Swing then you might be doing something differently in your Swing code, such as using a `SwingWorker`. If you aren't using a `SwingWorker` (or equivalent) then you're getting lucky—accessing the UI in Swing or JavaFX on a background thread can lead to _undefined behavior_. In other words, your code may _appear_ to be working but it's actually incorrect.

Comment: @Slaw I have checked `javafx.concurrent.Task` and there are many examples that confusing me. So could you please help me giving an example how to achieve that according to my current scenario? I have updated the question with my button click event and key event.

Comment: @TechGuy go through them one by one (they are simple examples) and apply each in a simplified context of your own. You will learn - and have to learn the basic concept, nobody can relieve you of that part :) - and at the end you can solve more complex problems. When understanding the basics, please come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates how some concrete problem (and minimal! and reproducible!) doesn't behave as you expect it.